# How To Send "Enter Key" via JavaScript in Selenium using "executeScript"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm working on automating a flow using IE 11 with Selenium and Java, on this web page I need to put a value in Text Box and then press Enter. I'm able to put the values using below code -

```
// Here Box is a webElement

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)iedriver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='1500';",box);
```

which is working as expected, but when I try to use `box.sendKeys(Keys.Enter)` it doesn't work. So what is the way I could achieve "pressing Enter key via JavaScript".

I have tried below code as well, but this is also not working.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(iedriver);
actions.moveToElement(box).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

There is no error message, code executes but on web page Enter Key is not pressed.

Comment: is there any button that says enter in UI ?

Comment: Why are you temped to use `JavascriptExecutor` in the first place? What is your exact usecase? Did you try the simple `sendKeys()`?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I have already used sendKeys and it is not working that's why I need to find a way to get it done via `JavascriptExecutor `

Comment: @cruisepandey, No, there is no button that says enter in UI. There is text box, which accepts some values as I have mentioned in my code, once I have given that value. I need to press enter, which is not working via `sendKeys`.

Comment: How do you login manually ?

Comment: @cruisepandey, there is no login, its a normal text box which shows no of records on the web page. I have set that value to 1500 so that 1500 records could be shown and I could read those many records. When the webpage loads it shows only 10 records, so I changed that value to 1500 but records are not shown till I press Enter.

Comment: try with this just give the xpath of input : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//")).sendKeys("Username"+Keys.ENTER);`

Comment: Have you looked to see if there's an event handler that may intercept the keyboard input and prevents it from being typed? Try looking for errors in the console also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via JavaScript you can consider using [KeyboardEvent.initKeyBoardEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent) function like:

```
document.body.dispatchEvent(document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent').initKeyEvent(
'keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0));
```

However I wouldn't recommend looking into that direction, instead you could try calling [submit()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#submit--) function on the [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) as simple as:

```
box.submit();
```

Also going forward consider refactoring your test suite to make use of [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) which allows you to abstract [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) elements representation from the test logic.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, I tried to use the code `box.submit()` as you suggested but i'm getting below error message -

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: Error executing JavaScript`

Comment: Good answer, though the last sentence about POM is completely irrelevant. First, it's not related to the question, and 2nd, there's nothing in his code that imply that he doesn't use POM. I recommend that you remove that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Java Robot to press the enter key?

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Don't forget the release key otherwise system will act as if the enter key is kept pressed down

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Well this might work if the web page is active or in Focus, but once the web page is running in background of web page is not in focus enter key would not work.

Comment: why would it be running in the background?

Comment: Since its flow is automated user would initiate the flow and continue his/her work so the system would be or would not be in Focus.